# Round-to-nearest function in Haskell

Tags: haskell, functional-programming, rounding

I need a function that rounds to the nearest number instead of the default one that rounds to even. I wrote one, but the thing is that I am new in Haskell and I think that it is having some syntax errors. Can someone please help me? Thanks.
Here is the code that I wrote so far:

```
rounding a
    | (round a) - a > (-0.5) = round a 
    | otherwise = round a + 1
```

Comment: If you do not tell us what syntax error you have, we cannot help you! I can only guess you mixed tabs and spaces.

Comment: @Franky Sorry I forgot. It compiles but then when you try to execute it... this happens http://prntscr.com/8yh8dd (A link to the screenshot)

Comment: I have to admit I giggled when I saw the title. (explanation: *(Round to nearest) function* versus *Round to (nearest function)*).

Comment: `round` also "rounds to the nearest number", of course. You presumably mean something else.

Comment: @BartekBanachewicz haha I was doing a literal translation from German

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are mixing types where you subtract `a` from `round a` (one has type depending on the type of the `rounding` argument while the other is always `Integral`). `round` requires `RealFrac` so that is the least you should require from the argument. As always, I would also suggest adding type signature to `rounding`. The following shows the simplest type of fix:

```
rounding a
    | (fromIntegral (round a)) - a > (-0.5) = round a
    | otherwise = round a + 1
```

Comment: I completely ignored your implementation and goal, and focused only on resolving the error.

Answer (score 3):

Why not

```
rounding a = floor (a + 0.5)
```

Comment: Thank you, this is a much cleaner/simpler solution. Can't believe that I didn't think of that in the first place!